# Writing a function batch file that returns 2 vectors from a sin function

Tags: matlab, function

I could use some help with a very basic, beginner function batch file.

I had to earlier write a batch file that generated and plotted a sinusoidal signal

f(t) = Acos(at)e^(-bt) for 0 <= t <= 10 with time increment of .1 sec and A = 3 a = 5 b = .2

I succesfully did this portion of the assignment by writing this code:

```
clc
clear

A = 3;
a = 5;
b = .2;

t = linspace(0,10,100);

f = A.*cos(a.*t).*exp(-b.*t);
plot(t,f);
title('My sin plot');
xlabel('Time');
ylabel('f');
grid;
```

Now I have to write a function batch file with the input arguments A, a, b.

That part is easy enough:

```
function [ sin_function ] = calc_sin_function( A, a, b )

t = linspace(0,10,100);

sin_function = A.*cos(a.*t).*exp(-b.*t);


end
```

However it also says the function should return f and t vectors, but should not plot anything. Then run the call function as

[f1, t1] = calc_sin_function(1,3,.3);

[f2, t2] = calc_sin_function(1,5,.1);

I'm really struggling to find what exactly this means to return these 2 vectors. I've tried creating empty vectors in my function block, but that doesn't seem to be the solution. I feel as if I'm just not experienced enough to understand what it means to return 2 vectors f and t.

Any help on what this means and how to get started would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I think you're supposed to write a [function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html) rather than a script. (Neither is a "batch" file.)

Comment: I don't think "batch file" is the right word: these are simply MATLAB functions. Have you read the "getting started" and similar documentation? Anyway, you need to use `function [outvar1, outvar2] = calc_sin_function(A,a,b)` and set `outvar1`, `outvar2` in your function.

Comment: In case the `sin_function`-vector is your `f`-vector in the calling lines, just add the `t` in the first line of the function so it says: `function [sin_function, t] = calc_sin_function(A,a,b)`.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you all are saying. Sorry about using "batch file" incorrectly. You're right I just had to declare my f and t vector in my function block to return both. I believe I have it correct now.

Comment: If your problem is solved, then consider either answering your own question (only if you think it could be helpful for future visitors), or deleting your question (if you don't).

Comment: In the link that I gave you above, the return values are called "outputs". Compare the example with one output to the example with multiple outputs.